# osclass current user id function returns 0 as result in plugin custom page

Tags: helper, userid, osclass, custom-pages

I want to list the current user items in my custom page and add some custom operations in that custom page, But i can't get current user id from hUsers helper using this function:

```
osc_user_id();
```

it returns 0 as the result.
what can i do to achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a custom plugin page, you have to export the user manually.

### How to export the user on custom page in Osclass

```
View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView("user", User::newInstance()->findByPrimaryKey($userId));
```

If you're in a controller,

```
$this->_exportVariableToView("user", User::newInstance()->findByPrimaryKey($userId));
```

Then, `$userId` will depend on which user you refer to:

- **You can get it from the URL:** use `Params::getParam('userId')` and passing it as a GET parameter.

  ```
  /index.php?page=custom&route=your_plugin_route&userId=12
  ```
- **Use the current logged user id:** `osc_logged_user_id()`

### See also

This tutorial on [how to develop Osclass plugins](https://wearemadhouse.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/how-to-develop-osclass-plugins/), might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to get logged user id and that was my fault. It fixed by using `osc_logged_user_id()` function